# Time Complexity of a recursive Reverse String

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I want to find the Time complexity in Big O of the following code:

```
ReverseString(S,x,y)
if x < y
    swap(S,x,y)
    return ReverseString(S,x+1,y-1)
```

The equation I got was

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = 3 + T(n+1)+ T(n-1)
```

If I'm right how would I go about solving this.

If I'm not right what is the correct equation.

Comment: I'm not sure what your T(n) is - complexity for a string of length n? Why would T(n) depend on the complexity of a longer string? The point of this method is that x starts at 0 and increases towards the middle and y starts at the end and decreases towards the middle. Naively these method walks the string once, using half the length of the string (rounded up) iterations, so should just be order of n shouldn't it?

Comment: T(n) is the standard task notation for recurrence relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that x and y are pointers to string ends, then your equation is wrong.  This is a simple, single recursion, but you've assumed double.  Also, there is the serious problem of making T(n) depend on T(n+1); you really don't want to go *up* in subscripts without a guaranteed, finite bounded decrease.

Think this way: each iteration gets x and y closer to each other by one character on each end.  Your single recursion loops through the halves of the string.  I would put the relation as

```
T(n) = 3 + T(n-1)
```

where n is half the length of the string (truncated if odd).